# audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) is not working

Tags: java, android, audio, vibration

whenever I use it, it crashes my application.
moreover, for vibration mode when I use `audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE)`it turns the "DO NOT DISTURB" on and it doesn't change the ringer mode to vibration.

this is main activity file.

```
package com.example.soundcontroller;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "Hani" ;
    Button ring,vibrate,mute;
    AudioManager audioManager;
  //  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Start");
        ring = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRing);
        vibrate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVibrate);
        mute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSilent);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int currentMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
        ring.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        mute.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        vibrate.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
       // mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: everything set");
      if (currentMode == audioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {

            ring.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: color set ringer");
        } else if (currentMode == audioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {

            mute.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: color set mute");
        } else if (currentMode == audioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) {

            vibrate.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: color set vibrate");
        }
        ring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: clicked on ring");
                try {
                    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }





                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ringer mode set to normal");
                ring.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
                vibrate.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                mute.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ring mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: clicked on mute");

                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                mute.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
                vibrate.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                ring.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Silent mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        vibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: clicked on vibrate");
                //if(mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter()==mNotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)
               //     mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                vibrate.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
                ring.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                mute.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vibration mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.soundcontroller">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnRing"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:text="Ring Mode"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSilent"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/btnRing"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:text="Silent Mode"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnVibrate"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSilent"
android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:text="Vibrate Mode"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i runned this app on my personal phone the vibration and normal(sound) mode is working alright, it wasnt working on simulator(virtual machine nexus 5, pixel something api 28 both) but silent mode is still not working

Comment: Please post here the minimal reproducible code so we can have look at what may be potentially causing the issue.

Comment: i posted the code please help me out

Comment: audioManager.getRingerMode() returns wrong value if phone ringer mode is set to silent/mute, it returns RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE instead of RINGER_MODE_SILENT in Android 6, and returns correct value on Android 9 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

when i manually gave the permission of DO NOT DISTURB to my application it starting working completely fine.